# What does "Disturb not X" mean?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, negation, imperatives, do-support

I already know what the word *disturb* means, but I do not understand what *disturb not* means. I’ve seen titles that start with this, like *Disturb Not the Dream* and *Disturb Not the Sleep*, etc.

What does *disturb not* mean? Why does *not* follow the verb? What does *not* apply to, the thing it follows or the thing it precedes?

Comment: It's just a poetic way of saying *don't disturb*. Similarly there is a flower called a *forget-me-not*.

Comment: One phrase that uses this word order and is actually appears fairly often in everyday conversation (in some parts of the English-speaking world) is "Fear not" (that is, "Do not fear"). But the same order exists in telescoped form in the standard order of the "to be" verb in interrogatives—"Isn't ["is not"] it a beautiful day?" "Aren't [are not] you clever!" It's just that when we use the uncontracted form of "isn't" and "aren't" in these cases, we transpose the pronoun and the "not": "Is it not a beautiful day?" "Are you not clever?"

Comment: It means the same thing as *don't disturb.*

Comment: **Gildor:** ‘That Gandalf should be late, does not bode well. But it is said: **“Do not meddle** in the affairs of Wizards, for they are subtle and quick to anger.” The choice is yours: to go or wait.’ //
**Frodo:** ‘And it is also said, **“Go not** to the elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes.“ ’

Comment: “He who **knows not** and **knows not** he **knows not,** he is a fool: shun him. He who **knows not** and knows he **knows not,** he is a child: teach him. He who knows and **knows not** he knows, he is asleep: wake him. He who knows and knows he knows, he is a teacher: heed him.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to **disturb**   [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/55820?rskey=JJV4WC&result=2&isAdvanced=true#eid6522370)

> To move anything from its settled condition or position; to unsettle.

As in the sense of *do not disturb*:

> - 1664   J. Evelyn Kalendarium Hortense / **Disturb not** their beds..lest    the seeds dry.

and

> - 1816   Shelley Alastor /   With lightning eyes, and eager breath, and    feet **Disturbing not** the drifted snow.

**Disturb not**, a much lesser used *do not disturb* and found in literary writings and prose.